# Updating non-trivial structures in polars cells

Tags: python, python-polars

Say I have this:

```
>>> polars.DataFrame([[(1,2),(3,4)],[(5,6),(7,8)]], list('ab'))
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────┬────────┐
│ a      ┆ b      │
│ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ object ┆ object │
╞════════╪════════╡
│ (1, 2) ┆ (5, 6) │
│ (3, 4) ┆ (7, 8) │
└────────┴────────┘
```

How would I go with updating the 2nd element of the tuple only? E.g. what do I need to do to get this:

```
┌────────┬────────┐
│ a      ┆ b      │
│ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ object ┆ object │
╞════════╪════════╡
│ (1, 9) ┆ (5, 9) │
│ (3, 9) ┆ (7, 9) │
└────────┴────────┘
```

where I've replaced the 2nd element of all tuples to 9.

Note that I'm not necessarily married to using tuples, but I'd like some kind of structure (dict, list, ...) as I want elements to have two pieces of information per cell due to a downstream requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update your version of polars you will get `list` columns.

```
df = pl.DataFrame([[(1,2),(3,4)],[(5,6),(7,8)]], list("ab"))
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌───────────┬───────────┐
│ a         ┆ b         │
│ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ [1, 2]    ┆ [5, 6]    │
│ [3, 4]    ┆ [7, 8]    │
└───────────┴───────────┘
```

I think you have to build a new list:

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.concat_list(pl.col(col).arr.first(), 9) 
   for col in df.columns
)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌───────────┬───────────┐
│ a         ┆ b         │
│ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ [1, 9]    ┆ [5, 9]    │
│ [3, 9]    ┆ [7, 9]    │
└───────────┴───────────┘
```

Or if you had struct columns:

```
(df.with_columns(pl.all().arr.to_struct(fields=["x", "y"]))
   .with_columns(
      pl.struct(pl.col(col).struct["x"], 9).alias(col)
      for col in df.columns
   )
)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌───────────┬───────────┐
│ a         ┆ b         │
│ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ struct[2] ┆ struct[2] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ {1,9}     ┆ {5,9}     │
│ {3,9}     ┆ {7,9}     │
└───────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: I like the struct approach as it doesn't rely on length 2 lists.

Comment: Nice thanks! Also appears that a list of dicts (e.g. `polars.DataFrame([[dict(x=1,y=2),dict(x=3,y=4)],[dict(x=5,y=6),dict(x=7,y=8)]], list("ab"))`) will now be converted to `struct`s, so that's great.

Answer (score 1):

To start, I'm not going to use tuples because then you get Object columns which have limited support. Let's just use lists because they're internally supported and have no downside relative to tuples since they're in arrow memory not python memory so the normal distinctions between tuples and lists don't apply

```
df = pl.DataFrame([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]], list('ab'))
```

Secondly, whenever you want to do something to list columns, it's almost always better to explode them first. I'm going to pretend we don't know which columns are lists and I'm going to use a temporary lazyframe to explode the columns. In each temporary lazyframe we're going to create a j column which represents the index list. From there we join each of those together. We do it that way incase the list columns are imbalanced. In this exact case you could skip most of this and just do a single `df.explode(['a','b'])` but this is (*mostly*) robust against imbalanced nested list size. I didn't test other input `df`s. Anyways, after you have all the internal lists exploded with an i and j index it's a simple matter of using `pl.when()` and then imploding the result.

```
lf=[]
for col, dtype in df.schema.items():
    if "List" not in str(dtype): continue
    smlf=(df.lazy()
                .with_row_count('i')
                .select('i', col, pl.arange(0, pl.col(col).arr.lengths()).alias("j"))
                .explode([col,"j"]))
    if isinstance(lf, list):
        lf=smlf
    else:
        lf=lf.join(smlf, on=['i','j'], how='outer')
    
lf=(
    lf
        .with_columns(
            pl.when(pl.col('j')==1)
                .then(pl.lit(9).alias(col))
                .otherwise(pl.col(col)) for col in [x for x in lf.columns if not x in ['i','j']])
        )
lf=lf.with_columns(pl.exclude(['i','j']).implode().over('i')).unique('i').drop('j').collect()
lf.drop('i')

shape: (2, 2)
┌───────────┬───────────┐
│ a         ┆ b         │
│ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ [3, 9]    ┆ [7, 9]    │
│ [1, 9]    ┆ [5, 9]    │
└───────────┴───────────┘
```

If your df had non-list columns that you want to retain then the last step would be

```
df.with_row_count('i').select(pl.exclude(lf.drop('i').columns)).join(lf, on='i').drop('i')
```

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks! I'll have to look into `explode` / `implode` a bit more, looks like it will be useful in other contexts as well.